# How to use Google Cloud Functions & Firestore as a task manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firestore to manage some distributed tasks on Google Cloud. Each task is a doc in the database, with status and other fields. I have cloud functions triggered by changes to the task docs. VM instances have similar docs too.

I have one cloud func `startReadyTasks` that checks all tasks & VMs, finds runnable tasks, and sends them to instances or starts instances for them. My problem is that because it's triggered by doc updates, that function can run multiple times at once, which means I start too many instances or start the tasks multiple times.

So I want a cloud function that can only run *one instance at a time*, which I know is not what it's meant for but it's what I need. The best plan I can come up for is this:

- When a task or VM is created or changes state, the cloud func handling those sets a special `check-requested` doc in the db to 1.
- I make `startReadyTasks` trigger on changes to `check-requested` and when it transitions to 1, it runs all its checks, starts instances, sends ready tasks off to run. Then when it's done, it sets `check-requested` to 0.

  - 1->1 transitions don't cause another trigger so I'll only get one running at a time.

This could miss requests while it's running, so it's not perfect. Also, you're not supposed to write to the same Firestore doc more than 1x/sec. Are there clever ideas or other Google infrastructure tools I can use to do this? Pub/sub? Preferably something not too complicated; seems like it should be a straightforward task.

(I tried a Firestore-based mutex, but that gets contention problems -- too many transactions on the same doc.)